# Need help setting up custom MailChimp subscription form

Tags: html, css, email, mailchimp, newsletter

So I had a pre-designed subscription sign up on my website and then I signed up for MailChimp and want to use them for email marketing. I'm having trouble merging my code with the default they give you. I thought I got it all working but when I submitted users my mail chimp mailing list contacts didn't update. Here is my code where I tried to convert it:

```css
.c-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.c-checkbox:checked + .c-formContainer .c-form {
  width: 14.5em;
}
.c-checkbox:checked + .c-formContainer .c-form__toggle {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.7);
}
.c-checkbox:checked + .c-formContainer .c-form__input, .c-checkbox:checked + .c-formContainer .c-form__buttonLabel {
  transition: 0.2s 0.1s;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.c-checkbox:not(:checked) + .c-formContainer .c-form__input:required:valid ~ .c-form__toggle::before, .c-checkbox:checked + .c-formContainer .c-form__input:required:valid ~ .c-form__toggle::before {
  content: 'Thank You! \1F436';
}
.c-checkbox:not(:checked) + .c-formContainer .c-form__input:required:valid ~ .c-form__toggle {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
.c-formContainer, .c-form, .c-form__toggle {
  width: 12em;
  height: 3.5em;
}
.c-formContainer {
  top: 2%;
  right: 1%;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.c-form, .c-form__toggle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 6.25em;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.c-form {
  top: 2%;
  left: 82%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 0.625em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0.125em 0.3125em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.c-form__toggle {
  color: #95b8c9;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.c-form__toggle::before {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  content: attr(data-title);
}
.c-form__input, .c-form__button {
  font: inherit;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.c-form__input, .c-form__buttonLabel {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.7);
  transition: 0s;
}
.c-form__input {
  color: #d1e0e8;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0.714em;
}
.c-form__input::placeholder {
  color: currentColor;
}
.c-form__input:required:valid {
  color: #95b8c9;
}
.c-form__input:required:valid + .c-form__buttonLabel {
  color: #fff;
}
.c-form__input:required:valid + .c-form__buttonLabel::before {
  pointer-events: initial;
}
.c-form__buttonLabel {
  color: #d1e0e8;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
.c-form__buttonLabel::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.c-form__button {
  color: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  height: 90%;
  width: 5em;
  background-color: #95b8c9;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<input class="c-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
      <div class="c-formContainer">
        <form class="c-form" action="https://my mailchimp subscriptin url" method="post">
          <input class="c-form__input" placeholder="E-mail" type="email"
            pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,63}$" required>
          <label class="c-form__buttonLabel" for="checkbox">
            <button class="c-form__button" type="button">Send</button>
          </label>
          <label class="c-form__toggle" for="checkbox" data-title="TAP IN"></label>

        </form>
      </div>
```

Then here is the mailchimp default, suggested form:

```html
<!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
 #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
 /* Add your own Mailchimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
    We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="https://my mailchimp subscriptin url" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
 
 <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_6dcd4cb8ab9377f4951e72570_03d6667079" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```